# My animation lags on web, aspecially on Safary

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I got a code for splash animation, you can check how it works here: https://dereza-92371.web.app/#/

I believe it happens because of the circle element that grows, but I just have no better way to build it.
The code is:

```
 class StaggerAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  StaggerAnimation({super.key, required this.controller})
      : _radius = Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
            parent: controller,
            curve: const Interval(
              0.0,
              0.4,
              curve: Curves.easeInOutCirc,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        _opacity = Tween<double>(
          begin: 0.0,
          end: 1.0,
        ).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
            parent: controller,
            curve: const Interval(
              0.3,
              0.6,
              curve: Curves.easeInOutCirc,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        _textOpacity = Tween<double>(
          begin: 0.0,
          end: 1.0,
        ).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
            parent: controller,
            curve: const Interval(
              0.4,
              0.8,
              curve: Curves.easeInOutCirc,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        _width = Tween<double>(
          begin: 0.0,
          end: 250.0,
        ).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(
            parent: controller,
            curve: const Interval(
              0.0,
              0.6,
              curve: Curves.easeInOutCirc,
            ),
          ),
        );

  final Animation<double> controller;
  final Animation<double> _opacity;
  final Animation<double> _width;
  final Animation<double> _radius;
  final Animation<double> _textOpacity;


  Widget _buildAnimation(BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
    var circleScale =
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
            ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.2
            : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1.2;

    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
      children: [
        CustomPaint(
          painter: RevealProgressButtonPainter(circleScale * _radius.value),
          child: Container(),
        ),
        Container(
          width: _width.value,
          height: _width.value,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: siteMode.splashShadowColor,
                blurRadius: 80.0,
                spreadRadius: 0.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Image.asset(
            siteMode.splashGoatLogo,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
            opacity: _opacity,
            cacheWidth: 250,
            cacheHeight: 250,
            filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
            child: Image.asset(
              siteMode.splashTextLogo,
              opacity: _textOpacity,
              width: 170,
              cacheWidth: 170,
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      builder: _buildAnimation,
      animation: controller,
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreenLogo extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreenLogo({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreenLogo> createState() => _SplashScreenLogoState();
}

class _SplashScreenLogoState extends State<SplashScreenLogo>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 4000), vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller.forward();
    //timeDilation = 10.0; // 1.0 is normal animation speed.
    return StaggerAnimation(controller: _controller.view);
  }
}

class RevealProgressButtonPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double _screenSize;
  RevealProgressButtonPainter(this._screenSize);
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = siteMode.splashBcgColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    canvas.drawCircle(
        Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2), _screenSize, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(RevealProgressButtonPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate._screenSize != _screenSize;
  }
}
```

I followed all the instruction on Flutter animation FAQ but still it is not smooth at all, please help.

Comment: Ddi you build with canvas kit or html renderer?

Comment: canvas --release

Comment: Try: ```flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html --release```

Comment: got now difference